# how to connect two rich text box

Tags: c#, winforms

I write a word processor, and I want to display the text on separate pages, like Microsoft Word, then I think do Collection of Rich Text Box, and I want that when a user typed in and filled the first box in the text, The cursor moves automatically the second box.
How can I do this? Is there any event activated when the text box is filled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this to build `OnVisibleScrollbarsChanged` event. http://www.csharp-examples.net/check-scrollbars-visibility/

Comment: Would you add some code showing how to use it regarding the question?

Comment: Yes, of course, The idea is that once added a scroll bar the size of the text box changes, then we will use the event "resize" To create new page and move the cursor to the new page.

Comment: this is the code: protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e) { base.OnResize(e); // the code }

Comment: Now I'm trying to understand it more deeply, I am impressed that a message is sent from the operating system to form when the text box fills up, and we can use it as well, which is a more correct, perhaps someone knows a message is sent?

Answer (score -1):

There are events which trigger when the textbox's text get changed.

So count the amount of text within that box, and if it reaches a certain amount - go to the next 'page'.

Comment: But the number of characters per page is not constant?

Comment: So how do you determine when its 'full' ? When the scrollbar appears? In that case you could check whether the scrollbar is visibile.

Comment: I'm not sure that would make for a nice user interface experience.

Comment: Once the scrollbar appears, remove the last character and move to the next one. Nobody gets to see it.

Comment: `Once the scrollbar appears` which event do you attach to to get this information?